# How to read a file into a String array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file "A.txt" in which I have stored five names:
"Alex","John","James","Marco","Roland"

I want to store each name as a single element of a String array:
String a[0] = "Alex";
String a[1] = "John";
And so on....

I tried to read the textfile with fileReader and the program looks like this,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A.txt"));
String a[] = {br.readLine()};
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
System.out.println(a[i]);
 }
```

The output comes out like this;
"Alex","John","James","Marco","Roland"
Null
Null
Null
Null

I want to store each name as a single element but a[0] stores the whole content of the text file.

I discovered that "A.txt" inside FileReader puts " " in the whole content of the text file something like this,
" "Alex","John","James","Marco","Roland" "
It should be,
"Alex","John","James","Marco","Roland"

Due to " " the whole content of text file gets converted into a single element in an array.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: split the string using comma. See String split method for more details.

Comment: Its already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A.txt");
String data = br.readLine();
String a[] = data.split(",");
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
   System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```